# Getting all items of lists in a list array

Tags: c++

#### Example of producing,

```
std::list<SomeClass*> products[4];

// styleProducts, itemProducts, ... are defined before. 
products[1] = styleProducts;
products[2] = itemProducts;

std::list<SomeClass*> allProducts; // so how to get all products ?
```

#### Description :

the code here is very simple where i can just use iterators to merge both 1, 2 indexes into one list, but my problem here, it would be up to 1000 products lists, so how can I get all!

#### Problem :

I want to merge all indexes of this array to be merged into one list.

Comment: It is not clear from your post what your problem is.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Post edited, updated example of producing.

Comment: Side Note: Do not use std::list, unless you know what for (for what, wherefore).

Comment: @DieterLücking What do you mean with "what for", explain please.

Comment: `std::list` is a linked-list, which in most cases, is not what is ideal. One should use `std::vector`, a self-growing contiguous array, in most situations.

Comment: Actually, i am in need of forward_list in this situation. Back to topic, how to get all indexes of an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
std::vector< std::list<SomeClass*>* > products;

products.push_back(&styleProducts);
products.push_back(&itemProducts);
// etc...

std::list<SomeClass*> allProducts;

for (std::vector< std::list<SomeClass*>* >::iterator iter = products.begin(); iter != products.end(); ++iter) {
    allProducts.merge(*iter);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <algorithm>

struct mergeWith
{
    std::list<SomeClass*> &m_dest;

    mergeWith(std::list<SomeClass*> &dest) : m_dest(dest) {}

    void operator()(std::list<SomeClass*> *l)
    {
        m_dest.merge(*l);
    }
};

std::vector< std::list<SomeClass*>* > products;

products.push_back(&styleProducts);
products.push_back(&itemProducts);
// etc...

std::list<SomeClass*> allProducts;
std::for_each(products.begin(), products.end(), mergeWith(allProducts));
```

If you are using C++11 or later:

```
std::vector< std::list<SomeClass*>* > products;

products.push_back(&styleProducts);
products.push_back(&itemProducts);
// etc...

std::list<SomeClass*> allProducts;

for (auto l: products) {
    allProducts.merge(*l);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::vector< std::list<SomeClass*>* > products;

products.push_back(&styleProducts);
products.push_back(&itemProducts);
// etc...

std::list<SomeClass*> allProducts;
std::for_each(products.begin(), products.end(), 
  [&](std::list<SomeClass*> *l) { allProducts.merge(*l); }
);
// if you are using C++14 or later, you can replace
// "std::list<SomeClass*> *l" in the lambda with "auto l"...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, it can be solved with the method .merge(otherlist).

Example:

```
std::list<int> list1 = { 5,9,0,1,3 };
std::list<int> list2 = { 8,7,2,6,4 };

list1.sort();
list2.sort();

list1.merge(list2);

std::cout << "merged: " << list1 << "\n";
```

**Output:** 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

More info in cppreference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/merge

Edit:

What about:

```
std::list<SomeClass*> allProducts;

for(int i=0; i<products.size(); ++i){
    allProducts.merge(products[i]);
}
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't be like that, what if I have list3, list4, listx..... This won't work.

Comment: Sure, it will. Declare an array or vector that holds a pointer to each of the desired lists, and then loop through the array/vector calling `allProducts.merge()` on each list.  Just like the answer shows.